# How to pass a function as parameter in another function?

Tags: function, rust

I am stuck with passing a function as a parameter:

```
fn first(
    a: *mut *const u8
) -> c_int;

fn second(
    b: u16,
    functionfirst: first()
) -> c_int;
```

the error I get is :

> ```
> error[E0573]: expected type, found function `first`
>
> functionfirst: first()
>
>                ^^^^ not a type
> ```

What I tried :

```
type first = Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(a: *mut *const u8) -> c_int>;

unsafe extern "C" fn second(
    b: u16,
    functionfirst: first
) -> c_int;
```

this also had an error:

> ```
> error: expected `;`, found `=`
>
> type first = Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(a: *mut *const u8) -> c_int>;
>
>            ^ expected `;`
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You're just dumping declarations out of the blue so it's a bit hard to understand [what you're actually aiming to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Furthermore this is not just Rust code consuming Rust functions, this seems to be FFI and interfacing Rust with some other system

> ```
> fn first(a: *mut *const u8) -> c_int;
> fn second(b: u16, functionfirst: first()) -> c_int;
> ```

Parameter types need to be types, `first()` is not a type, it's a function (call). The type of a function pointer is `fn(args…) -> result`. Though that tells rustc to use the Rust calling conventions, given the non-Rust types involved (though the mix of rust and non-rust numeric types sounds like a bad idea) you probably want an `extern` to ensure the correct ABI:

```rust
fn second(
    b: u16,
    functionfirst: extern fn(*mut *const u8) -> c_int
) -> c_int;
```

> What I tried : […] this also had an error:

Providing code and errors in full (aka minimal reproducible examples) tends to be useful, because while I do get an error with your snippet it has *nothing to do* with the one you get.

I just get an error that a free function needs a body, which is solved by putting the declaration inside an `extern` block (to indicate that we're declaring a function provided by something else, rather than *defining* a function), then the compiler complains about the `unsafe` because `extern` blocks don't allow `unsafe` (as functions declared in them are unsafe by definition).

After these fixing these issues, both compile, for what little that's worth: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67e75201f7c2d8fa9bd474c6615cd414

Answer (score 0):

To pass a function to another function in Rust, you use a generic parameter with a trait bound. The most basic example is:

```
fn hi_5<F>(func: F) where F: Fn(u32) -> u32, {
    println!("Hi, {}", func(5));
}
fn square(x: u32) -> u32 {
    x*x
}
hi_5(square);
```

To break this down, here we declare a function called `hi_5` (`fn hi_5`), which has a generic parameter F (`<F>`) and takes one parameter, of type F (`func: F`). The F generic type has an `Fn(u32) -> u32` trait bound on it (`where F: Fn(u32) -> u32`), which means it's a function that takes a single `u32` and return an `u32`.

In Rust there are three `Fn` traits, though they are only important if you're dealing with closures.

- The `Fn` trait is what you use most often. It borrows immutably all
  the variables from the environment.
- The `FnMut` trait borrows the environment mutably, meaning it can
  change its values.
- The `FnOnce` trait moves the used environment variables into the
  closure. The `Once` part comes from the fact, that after calling
  the function once it cannot be called again.

If you don't understand what "the environment" is, check out [this chapter from the Rust book talking about closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch13-01-closures.html#capturing-the-environment-with-closures).

Answer (score -2):

Inspired by the [Iterator::find](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#2323-2326) sources.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=769d0d84634baa8218a19e6355b77ef5)

```
fn find<P>(mut predicate: P)
    where
        P: FnMut(&str) -> bool,
    {
        predicate("x");
    }
fn main() {
    find(|x| {println!("Printed {}", x); return true; });
}
```

[Fn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html):-

> The version of the call operator that takes an immutable receiver.
> Instances of Fn can be called repeatedly without mutating state.

[FnMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html):-

> The version of the call operator that takes a mutable receiver.
> Instances of FnMut can be called repeatedly and may mutate state.